# 3-D graphs in C using Matplotlib of Python

Tags: matplotlib

I needed to draw 3-d graphs using **C** code. For this purpose i have to include the matplotlib of Python. Anyone help to do this?? I have to plot the graph on the values currently placed in an array of **C**.

Comment: Could you clarify the use of C? Matplotlib is a Python library. It can make very nice 3dplots using the `mplot3d` portion of matplotlib.

Comment: I mean i need to plot the graphs using matplotlib in C language. I don't know how to do this? On the internet the solutions are ambiguous i could not understand?

Answer (score 3):

Although not exactly the same question you might want to take a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509156/anyone-knows-a-matplotlib-equivalent-in-c-or-c).

That being said some of the solutions proposed are:

**A)** That you include Python on you C program (by @Raj):

```
#include "Python.h"

int main()
{
   Py_Initialize();
   PyRun_SimpleString("import pylab");
   PyRun_SimpleString("pylab.plot(range(5))");
   PyRun_SimpleString("pylab.show()");
   Py_Exit(0);
   return 0;
}
```

**B)** That you use libraries that mimic matplotlib (by @kazemakase):

[matplotlib-cpp](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp)

As for the array issue, depending on the solution that you chose, it might be worth your while to look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459479/how-to-return-an-c-array-to-python). In here @en_Knight provide a few recipes for transforming data (C to Python and vice-versa). Example:

```
int* my_data_to_modify;
if (PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &numpy_tmp_array)){
        /* Point our data to the data in the numpy pixel array */
        my_data_to_modify = (int*) numpy_tmp_array->data;
}
```